# How to allocate memory?

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management

I am trying to create a linked list in my program and I am not able to allocate memory to the structure pointer using malloc(). How do I allocate memory to variables in GCC? The sample program is given below. How to make it work in gcc?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <alloc.h>
struct node
{

    int data;
    struct node * link;

};
void insert (struct node *p, int d)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=d;
    temp->link=NULL;

        if(p==NULL)
        {
            p=temp;
        }
        else{
        while(p->link!=NULL)
            p=p->link;

    p->link=temp;
        }
}
void disp(struct node *p)
{
    while(p!=NULL)
        {
        printf("%d\n",p->data);
        p=p->link;
        }


}

int main()
{

struct node *p;
p=NULL;
insert(p,7);
insert(p,9);
disp(p);

}
```

The error I'm encountering is:

```
Line 18: error: alloc.h: No such file or directory
In function 'insert':
Line 13: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`malloc` is in `<stdlib.h>`. Include that.

Reading the man page for that function would have given you that information. It's not compiler-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error is gone but still am not getting any output.. Can you find any bug in the code?

Comment: I can spot at least one: you assume that `p=temp;` in `insert` will change the value of `p` in main. This is not the case. You should modify `insert` to return the node pointer, or use a pointer-to-pointer. Please read the hundreds of examples of linked list implementations available here and on google.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`, so that's what you want to `#include`.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of malloc is in the `stdlib.h` file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

instead of `alloc.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others say: your error occurs because you have to include `stdlib.h` instead of `alloc.h`

To get your list printed, you have to modify `p` in `insert`. Currently, you're passing `NULL` every time you call `insert`. Change your code that way (pass a pointer-to-pointer to `insert`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node * link;
};

/* note **p instead of *p */
void insert (struct node **p, int d)
{
  struct node *temp;
  temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  temp->data=d;
  temp->link=NULL;
  if(*p==NULL)
  {
    *p=temp;
  }
  else{
    while((*p)->link!=NULL)
      *p=(*p)->link;
    (*p)->link=temp;
  }
}

void disp(struct node *p)
{
  while(p!=NULL)
  {
    printf("%d\n",p->data);
    p=p->link;
  }
}

int main()
{
  struct node *p;
  p=NULL;
  insert(&p,7);
  insert(&p,9);
  disp(p);
}
```

and it will print

```
7
9
```